# React state issue: Empty strings appending after first entry instead of submitted names

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, react-state

I'm working on a React app where users can add their names to a list. I'm facing a strange issue where the input field mysteriously clears after the first name is entered. Subsequent entries appear as empty strings in the list.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  let myNameElement = useRef();
  let [myNameArray, setMyNameArray] = useState([]);

  function handelAdd(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setMyNameArray((prevValue) => {
      let updatedMyNameArray = [...prevValue, myNameElement.current.value];
      myNameElement.current.value = ""; // Tried placing here
      return updatedMyNameArray;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form action="" onSubmit={handelAdd}>
        <input
          ref={myNameElement}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your name..."
        />
        <button>Add</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        {myNameArray.map((myName, index) => (
          <h1 key={index}>{myName}</h1>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**What I've Tried:**

- I tried clearing the input field both before and after the state update (commented lines), but neither worked(Previously `myNameElement.current.value = "";` was placed outside the event handler).
- I checked the React DevTools, and the myNameArray state seems to update
  correctly with each name.

**Possible Causes (I need your help here):**

- Is there something I'm missing about React state updates and re-renders?
- Could there be another hidden side effect causing the clear?

**An alternative way to achieve the desired behavior:**

If I write

```
setMyNameArray([...myNameArray, myNameElement.current.value]);
    myNameElement.current.value = "";
```

in place of

```
setMyNameArray((prevValue) => {
      let updatedMyNameArray = [...prevValue, myNameElement.current.value];
      myNameElement.current.value = ""
```

then everything works just fine.

**I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions! Thanks in advance!**

Comment: what to you mean "Subsequent entries appear as empty strings in the list." ? did you log `myNameArray` what exactly was inside?

Comment: All the entries that I enter after the first one appear empty. An empty h1 with no name gets appended.

Comment: Also this " input field mysteriously clears after the first name is entered." is weird you clear the ref yourself so why are you surprised the input is cleared?

Comment: According to the docs https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs using refs will lead to unreliable rerenders

Comment: The problem is that the updater function you pass to set state must be **pure**. Yours is not because you are modifying ref inside it. But despite it is a bit strange behavior because you copied a primitive value `myNameElement.current.value` to the `updatedMyNameArray` so the afterwards modification (setting to empty string) of that ref should not have had impact on the `updatedMyNameArray` contents (which apparently it does because you are seeing empty strings inside state array).

Comment: Could this be because in development mode Rect will rerender the component twice and the first time it will have the value set in the input field and the second time it will try to access the current value it will be empty because it is being cleared?

Comment: @Balaji I posted similar answer, seems like that - check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Subsequent entries appear as empty strings in the list.

Here is my possible explanation why this is happening.
Here:

```
 setMyNameArray((prevValue) => {
      let updatedMyNameArray = [...prevValue, myNameElement.current.value];
      myNameElement.current.value = ""; // Tried placing here
      return updatedMyNameArray;
 });
```

Here you are violating react rule that if you use updater function with the set state it must be **pure**. By modifying the ref inside the function this is not pure anymore.

Now, react may **double invoke** the updater function in strict mode to help you detect impure functions. Apparently that is what it does here, on the first invocation, you did put the value of the input inside the array. But then you clear the ref (set to empty string). Then what react does it invokes this updater **second time**, at that point, the `myNameElement.current.value` is empty string (due to previous invocation). And that is the one that gets written to state. That is why you see empty strings in the state array.

---

To support my explanation I removed `StrictMode` and this behavior doesn't happen anymore, that is, no more empty strings inside state.